# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError How to solve this issue?

Tags: java, compiler-errors

I am having the following error when running this code:

Here is the full Stackflow, any input would be appreciated;

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: ExecuteQuiz
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ExecuteQuiz
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
```

Any idea why? I have 7 other classes involved with the project but have never seen this error.

```
    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Collections;
    import java.util.Scanner;

    public class ExecuteQuiz {

    static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // ask the user for the filename
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Which quiz are you taking? ");
        String theFile = scan.nextLine(); // file may contain more than one word
        File fileIn = new File(theFile);

        // ask the user for another filename if the given file doesn't exist
        // exists() method in File class - checks whether file
        // exists and is readable
        while (!fileIn.exists()) {
            System.out.print("Invalid file name! Try again: ");

            theFile = scan.nextLine();

            fileIn = new File(theFile);
        }

        // have a valid file name, create a Scanner object
        Scanner fileScan = new Scanner(fileIn);

        // An arraylist of ALL problems.
        ArrayList<Problem> problems = new ArrayList<Problem>();

        // process the file
        while (fileScan.hasNextLine()) {
            String type = scan.nextLine(); // Get the line in a string
            String question = scan.nextLine();

            switch (type) {
            case "W":
                String WAnswer = scan.nextLine();
                WProblem w = new WProblem(question, WAnswer);
                problems.add(w);
                break;
            case "T":
                String TString = scan.nextLine(); // Gets the string
                boolean TAnswer = Boolean.parseBoolean(TString); // Converts to
                                                                    // boolean
                TProblem t = new TProblem(question, TAnswer); // Creates the
                                                                // object
                problems.add(t);
                break;
            case "N":
                String Nanswer = scan.nextLine();
                NProblem n = new NProblem(question, Nanswer);
                problems.add(n);
                break;
            case "S":
                ArrayList<String> options = new ArrayList<String>();
                // Get the answer and add it to the options
                String SAnswer = input.nextLine();
                options.add(SAnswer);

                // add the rest of options
                while (input.nextLine() != null) {
                    String option = input.nextLine();
                    options.add(option);
                }
                // Create new objects
                SProblem s = new SProblem(question, SAnswer, options);

                problems.add(s);
                break;
            case "M":
                ArrayList<String> MAnswer = new ArrayList<String>();
                ArrayList<String> MOptions = new ArrayList<String>();

                // Find all the answers
                while (input.nextLine() != null) {
                    String answer = input.nextLine();
                    MAnswer.add(answer);
                    MOptions.add(answer);
                }

                // get the rest of the options
                while (input.nextLine() != null) {
                    MOptions.add(input.nextLine());
                }

                MProblem m = new MProblem(question, MAnswer, MOptions);
                problems.add(m);
                break;
            case "O":
                // Adding answers into an arraylist
                ArrayList<String> OrderedAnswer = new ArrayList<String>();

                // Add the answers in order
                while (input.nextLine() != null) {
                    OrderedAnswer.add(input.nextLine());
                }
                OProblem o = new OProblem(question, OrderedAnswer);
                problems.add(o);
                break;
            }
            // Analyze the type of problem

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: please give the Stacktrace.

Comment: how are you running the program

Comment: @MayankSharma  Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: ExecuteQuiz
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ExecuteQuiz
 at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
 at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)

Comment: Is your class file (or jar) in the classpath?

Comment: you try to run ExecuteQuiz from the Projec right.?? no JAR required right.?

Comment: do you have other classes with `main()`? are you creating object of `ExecuteQuiz`  in that class? are you using an IDE like eclipse or running it from command line ? post the command line commands if you are executing it from command line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your class has major compile time issues. have you even compiled the code and checked..??

the switch case is giving the error in compilation: Incompatible Types

the class has not compiled and you are trying to directly run it..thus no class definition found error .

try to change the part :

```
case "W":
```

to

```
case 1:
```

compile and then run

I used the below code:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class ExecuteQuiz {

    static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // ask the user for the filename
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Which quiz are you taking? ");
        String theFile = scan.nextLine(); // file may contain more than one word
        File fileIn = new File(theFile);

        // ask the user for another filename if the given file doesn't exist
        // exists() method in File class - checks whether file
        // exists and is readable
        while (!fileIn.exists()) {
            System.out.print("Invalid file name! Try again: ");

            theFile = scan.nextLine();

            fileIn = new File(theFile);
        }

        // have a valid file name, create a Scanner object
        Scanner fileScan = new Scanner(fileIn);

        // An arraylist of ALL problems.
        ArrayList<Problem> problems = new ArrayList<Problem>();

        // process the file
        while (fileScan.hasNextLine()) {
            int type = Integer.parseInt(scan.nextLine()); // Get the line in a string
            String question = scan.nextLine();

            switch (type) {
            case 1:
                String WAnswer = scan.nextLine();
                WProblem w = new WProblem(question, WAnswer);
                problems.add(w);
                break;
            case 2:
                String TString = scan.nextLine(); // Gets the string
                boolean TAnswer = Boolean.parseBoolean(TString); // Converts to
                // boolean
                TProblem t = new TProblem(question, TAnswer); // Creates the
                // object
                problems.add(t);
                break;
            case 3:
                String Nanswer = scan.nextLine();
                NProblem n = new NProblem(question, Nanswer);
                problems.add(n);
                break;
            case 4:
                ArrayList<String> options = new ArrayList<String>();
                // Get the answer and add it to the options
                String SAnswer = input.nextLine();
                options.add(SAnswer);

                // add the rest of options
                while (input.nextLine() != null) {
                    String option = input.nextLine();
                    options.add(option);
                }
                // Create new objects
                SProblem s = new SProblem(question, SAnswer, options);

                problems.add(s);
                break;
            case 5:
                ArrayList<String> MAnswer = new ArrayList<String>();
                ArrayList<String> MOptions = new ArrayList<String>();

                // Find all the answers
                while (input.nextLine() != null) {
                    String answer = input.nextLine();
                    MAnswer.add(answer);
                    MOptions.add(answer);
                }

                // get the rest of the options
                while (input.nextLine() != null) {
                    MOptions.add(input.nextLine());
                }

                MProblem m = new MProblem(question, MAnswer, MOptions);
                problems.add(m);
                break;
            case 6:
                // Adding answers into an arraylist
                ArrayList<String> OrderedAnswer = new ArrayList<String>();

                // Add the answers in order
                while (input.nextLine() != null) {
                    OrderedAnswer.add(input.nextLine());
                }
                OProblem o = new OProblem(question, OrderedAnswer);
                problems.add(o);
                break;
            }
            // Analyze the type of problem

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The user is probably on jdk 7, which has improved case syntax.

Comment: But the file it is reading will have letters, not numbers. thus, why I have the letters in the switch. It's for a premade text file.

Comment: make a translation text...the switch case only works with int values..

also try to check it with ENUMs...i think it works with that but i am not sure...

Comment: @VineetVerma http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html  You can have strings

Comment: please see if your code is compiling.. i am getting too many errors in your codecompilation

Comment: check if in the class path the compiled class is available or not. the java class is one thing, check if the .class file is available in the class path.. if not then it is a compilation issue

Comment: I deleted all of the code in the main and still get the error @VineetVerma so I do not believe it is the switch

Comment: i just ran the code after some minor changes...it executed just fine...

again..as Alex said...go to your class path and check if the compiled class is available there..if not then that is you problem

Comment: also the java doc says that the String comparison is Java SE 7 and above. "In Java SE 7 and later, you can use a String object in the switch statement's expression."

do you have java 7...??

Comment: @VineetVerma what changes did you make?

Comment: @VineetVerma So you are going to simply add every piece of Java executable that you've developed yourself to your class path to run them from anywhere. Nice.

Comment: @mostruash: Just the ones that fail to reach the class path automatically due to some or the other error in the IDE.

Answer (score 0):

It seems ExecuteQuiz class is not on classpath. Set it in classpath.

If you are on windows you can set it as below

```
set CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%.;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not a compiler error.

Typical way to launch java application is `java -classpath <path> FullyQualifiedClassName`

FullyQualifiedClassName in your case is `ExecuteQuiz`

Once compiled your classes will be forming a directory structure matching the classes.  Provide the root of the that tree as part of classpath. You should also add any other dependency like jars.

More reference  [on how classes are found](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/findingclasses.html)